# Cannot assign to generic property in protocol

Tags: swift, generics

I'd like to know if there's something simple that I'm missing here in this code or if it's just a mix of Swift trickeries that are preventing me from doing what I want.

I'm allowing types implementing the `Foo` protocol to contain an `entity` property of any type, as long as it conforms to `StringIdentifiable`:

```
protocol StringIdentifiable {
  var id: String? { get }
}

protocol Foo: class {
  associatedtype AnyStringIdentifiable: StringIdentifiable
  var entity: AnyStringIdentifiable? { get set }
}
```

As of Swift 3.1, this "any type" part [wouldn't be possible](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-522) if not using the `associatedtype`. Going ahead, let's say I have another protocol that requires a `Foo` property. However, `Foo` is generic, so as you may know we can't do that because *"generic protocols can only be used as a generic constraint"*. Trying to avoid the type erasure mess, I decided to use another `associatedtype` in my second protocol and the compiler doesn't complain:

```
protocol Bar {
  //var foo: Foo { get set } // can't do because Foo is generic
  associatedtype AnyFoo: Foo
  var foo: AnyFoo { get set }
}
```

But now, if I try to set something in `foo`, the compiler will complain:

```
extension Bar {
  func setEntity(_ entity: StringIdentifiable) {
    foo.entity = entity
  }
}
```

The error is *Cannot assign value of type 'StringIdentifiable' to type '_?'*

Note: this question's code is testable in a playground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

protocol StringIdentifiable {
    var id: String? { get }
}

protocol Foo: class {
    associatedtype AnyStringIdentifiable: StringIdentifiable
    var entity: AnyStringIdentifiable? { get set }
}

protocol Bar {
    //var foo: Foo { get set } // can't do because Foo is generic
    associatedtype AnyFoo: Foo
    var foo: AnyFoo { get set }
}

extension Bar {
    func setEntity(_ entity: AnyFoo.AnyStringIdentifiable) {
        foo.entity = entity
    }
}
```

Within Bar you can use `AnyFoo.AnyStringIdentifiable` to make sure the types are correct when setting `foo.entity`, because `foo.entity` is of the type `AnyFoo.AnyStringIdentifiable`.

Comment: It's just the type system helping you out! Think about it- for a given Bar, you know it has a `AnyFoo` that is a `Foo`. `AnyFoo` has a `AnyStringIdentifiable` who is always a `StringIdentifiable`. Just because two things are both a `AnyFoo`, doesn't mean that they both share the same `AnyStringIdentifiable`. So you don't have enough knowledge from the viewpoint of `Bar` to know what type of `StringIdentifiable` you need. But `Bar` knows what type of `Foo` it has, and that `Foo` knows what type of `StringIdentifiable` it has. So you have to address it that way: `AnyFoo.AnyStringIdentifiable`.

Comment: right now I don't agree with that... first, the Any stuff are associatedtypes. I don't like the fact that I'm able to refer to these types outside the protocol itself. Being able to call AnyStringIdentifiable from inside Bar is very weird. Second, I believe there is enough knowledge from the Bar's point of view, Bar knows it has something that is a Foo and Foos have something that is StringIdentifiable. The fact that they have "Any" in front of them (as an associatedtype) just makes it even more generic (although it shouldn't be needed if SR-522 had been addressed)